# MYSQL: Setting column value based on count grouped by other columns

Tags: mysql

I have the table, which has following Columns:

```
+-----------------------------+-------+---------------+----------------+
| School_Name                 | Class | ClassFiveSize | ClassEightSize |
+-----------------------------+-------+---------------+----------------+
| Tando Ghulam Ali-I          |     5 |          NULL |           NULL |
| Tando Ghulam Ali-I          |     5 |          NULL |           NULL |
| Tando Ghulam Ali-I          |     8 |          NULL |           NULL |
| Model School (E.M) Larkano. |     5 |          NULL |           NULL |
| Model School (E.M) Larkano. |     5 |          NULL |           NULL |
| Model School (E.M) Larkano. |     8 |          NULL |           NULL |
| Model School (E.M) Larkano. |     5 |          NULL |           NULL |
| Model School (E.M) Larkano. |     8 |          NULL |           NULL |
```

I want to set values in ClassFiveSize & ClassEightSize columns based on the count of School names, like:

```
+-----------------------------+-------+---------------+----------------+
| School_Name                 | Class | ClassFiveSize | ClassEightSize |
+-----------------------------+-------+---------------+----------------+
| Tando Ghulam Ali-I          |     5 |          2    |           1    |
| Tando Ghulam Ali-I          |     5 |          2    |           1    |
| Tando Ghulam Ali-I          |     8 |          2    |           1    |
| Model School (E.M) Larkano. |     5 |          3    |           2    |
| Model School (E.M) Larkano. |     5 |          3    |           2    |
| Model School (E.M) Larkano. |     8 |          3    |           2    |
| Model School (E.M) Larkano. |     5 |          3    |           2    |
| Model School (E.M) Larkano. |     8 |          3    |           2    |
```

Please let me know how to do it.

I am doing something like this:

```
update tableName t
inner join (
    select School_Name, count(*) counter
    from tableName
    where Class=8  group by School_Name ) g on g.School_Name = t.School_Name
set t.ClassEightSize = case when t.Class=8 then g.counter else 0 end;
```

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY? And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation in a query that returns the counters for each case and join it to the table:

```
update tablename t inner join ( 
  select School_Name, 
    sum(Class = 5) counter5,
    sum(Class = 8) counter8
  from tablename  
  group by School_Name 
) g on g.School_Name = t.School_Name 
set
  t.ClassFiveSize = g.counter5,
  t.ClassEightSize = g.counter8;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/anvf3c5Zjum2ePqLtQe2gx/0).
Results:

```
| School_Name                 | Class | ClassFiveSize | ClassEightSize |
| --------------------------- | ----- | ------------- | -------------- |
| Tando Ghulam Ali-I          | 5     | 2             | 1              |
| Tando Ghulam Ali-I          | 5     | 2             | 1              |
| Tando Ghulam Ali-I          | 8     | 2             | 1              |
| Model School (E.M) Larkano. | 5     | 3             | 2              |
| Model School (E.M) Larkano. | 5     | 3             | 2              |
| Model School (E.M) Larkano. | 8     | 3             | 2              |
| Model School (E.M) Larkano. | 5     | 3             | 2              |
| Model School (E.M) Larkano. | 8     | 3             | 2              |
```

Comment: Again, thank you for such a wonderful solution, and for being so kind! :)